iTextSharp PDF generation issue: CMYK color space not maintained
If I generate the PDF file from CorelDRAW and check its metadata, it shows the color format as CMYK, which is what I expected. However, when I generate the PDF from iTextSharp, its metadata shows ICC_Based. Printing is faded in iTextSharp because it doesn’t maintain the CMYK color space. What could be causing this? I want to generate a PDF in CMYK from iTextSharp. You can check both files here
tried everything, but nothing works. I expected iTextSharp to generate a CMYK PDF like CorelDRAW, but it shows ICC_Based and results in faded printing. Can't find any help on forums either

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please also share the source image from which iTextSharp creates the PDF.

https://itext-questions.narkive.com/bNTOPJlo/color-problem-in-creating-pdf-using-cmyk-images might be related to your issue.

(to put it here in case link goes dead, some PDF viewers - and maybe printers? - don't support ICC color profiles, which iTextSharp relies upon.)
